# Check if a land parcel (polygon) has access on a road or not

Tags: arcobjects

I have a feature layer with land parcels as polygons. Polygons (land parcels) are either adjacent in all its around sides by other polygons but some of them have a road a which is not actually a feature layer representing roads but is just an empty space between parcels. In this case, parcels have access to roads. The question is how can I automattically check if a polygon has access onto a road using VBA and AcrObjects.

Thanks
Deme

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest would be building a topology for your data and then validating the data on the same.

If you see the [Topology Poster](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/pdf/Topology_rules_poster.pdf), you will find a polygon rule which says *"Must not have gaps"*...you can use this rule to build topology and then validate your data against it. All the dirty areas will have the polygons with gaps, and that's what you need.

Refer the AO code [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1407&t=94875).

Cheers!

Comment: Just curious, is this a one time activity or a repetitive one?

Comment: It is a one time activity to check all the parcels and fill a field with yes/no.